# "fall in love with one of the twins" or "fall in love with one of twins"?

Tags: grammar

I am talking about the idea in general, so any twin, or a person at random.

Still, I think "the twins" is correct, but I am wondering if the alternative is also correct. I am not 100% sure. It looks to me that both can be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are grammatical, and each refers to a single person:

> I fell in love with **one of the** twins.
>   I fell in love with **one of two** twins.
>   I fell in love with **the** twin.
>   I fell in love with **a** twin.
>   I fell in love with **one** twin.
>   I fell in love with **some** twin.

The following are grammatical, and each refers to two or more people:

> I fell in love with **the** twins.
>   I fell in love with **two** twins.
>   I fell in love with **several** twins.
>   I fell in love with **the pair of** twins.
>   I fell in love with **a pair of** twins.
>   I fell in love with **some** twins.

However, your second sentence is ungrammatical:

> ✘ I fell in love with **one of** twins.

Answer (score 1):

A search online shows that 'one of twins' is used, but very rarely. The first results are mostly about medical research: '[Name of condition] in one of twins'.

Your question is about the 'idea in general', but Jason's examples are specifically about "I fell in love with ...". A more general statement is "It must be strange to fall in love with one of twins", which sounds grammatically acceptable to me. Even so, it would be more natural to say "It must be strange to fall in love with a twin" or "with one of a pair/set of twins". I would even *just* accept the sentence which Jason rejects: "I fell in love with one of twins", but similarly it would be more natural to say "I fell in love with a twin" or "with one of a pair/set of twins".